# How to write a SharePoint (2007) Enhancement to allow ShortCuts / Links in Document Libraries?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Hi
Right now it seems impossible to add a regular "link" or "shortcut" in Share Point built in Document Libraries. the need for shortcuts is clear, as you might want to have references from related folders / categories

Is there a way to write an addon / modify this web part / inherit it so it will allow regular .lnk windows shortcuts? (or any other alternative to references)

And while at it, how can I modify this web part and add an "UP" folder button. (and potentially also a tree view).

I guess I'm trying to make it behave more like Windows Explorer

I'm new to SharePoint programming, but have some .NET experience

Comment: For your navigation need, I would advice to either use straight away or investigate the solution provided by the kid that will add a handy "up" button to navigate in the folders hierarchy

http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2008/11/03/adding-an-up-folder-button-to-a-sharepoint-list-view-webpart.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears SharePoint *does* allow links (not .lnk files but built in document links), it just hides it well

**To enable it:**

- Go to a document library,
- Click `Settings`
- Then `Document Library Settings`
- And then `Advanced Settings`
- Set `Allow Management Of Content Types` to `Yes`,

**Then go back to Document Library Settings:**

- Select `Add From Existing Site Content Types`
- Add the `Link To a Document` content type

Now you can add links to other documents (just name the document and supply a URL)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your document library to behave like Explorer, I suggest you just use Explorer to open the document library using WebDav. Start at \servername\DavWWWRoot\ or \servername\DavWWWRoot\subsitename and navigate from there.

If you try to put a .lnk file in there it will probably be blocked and you will need to remove it from the list of blocked file types (think carefully before doing this).